# spring boot 3 how to specify multiple request matchers

Tags: java, angular, http, spring-security, cors

I am using spring security, and I would like to know how to add multiple request matchers, one for "auth / **" (which should allow anonymous requests) and "prod / **" (which should allow only if authenticated).
I am using spring boot 3

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        return http
            .csrf(csrf -> 
                csrf
                .disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authRequest) ->{
              authRequest
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().anonymous();
              authRequest.anyRequest().authenticated();
            }
                )
            .sessionManagement(sessionManager->
                sessionManager 
                  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
            
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your problem you have to rewrite this part of `SecurityFilterChain` to meet that you want to achieve.

```
…
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authRequest) ->{
                  authRequest
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
                }
                    )
…
```

To have more details about how it work and also why it should be so I really suggest to check/read [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) part about it and also a good advice for you is to go through all documentation because it is the best way to understand.